# How to add same field in child documents in solr

Tags: solr

I have the following indexed documents

{

```
"id":"data1",
"isParent":"1",
"_childDocuments":[
    {
        "description":"Benefit and Payroll consultant with HR team ",
        "isParent":"2",
        "exp":2
    },
    {
        "description":" ERP Avalon Implementation and Support Payroll",
        "isParent":"2",
        "exp":5
    }
]
```

}

When I search for children document whose exp is 7 I should get the above parent document.How can I achieve this.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block join query to let Solr know that you are looking to retertive the parent.

example
`http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionName?q={!parent which=isParent:1}exp:7`

Comment: Thanks for your response..I need to sum the experience of each child document that matches the description like payroll .I have tried with below query.But no luck!{!frange l=3}{!parent which=isParent:1 score=total v=$chq} AND chq=+ isParent:2 AND description:payroll AND {!func}exp